# manipulate one column based on the first 4 digits of another column PySpark

Tags: string, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame looking like this

```
code 1      code 2               Fruit_Group           temp_code
(string)   (string)              (string)             (boolean)
 
12E5-11     12E5-11                Apple              True 
12E5-11     ERE5-11,12E5-11        Apple              True
12E5-11     MMMM-11                Apple              True       #color to be changed 
12E5-11     XXXX-11                Apple              False       #color to be changed
12E5-11     12E5-11                Apple              True 
12E5-11     12E5-11, ERE5-11       Apple              True
```

By default the `Fruit_Group` is assigned to some fruits:.

The color remains **Apple** when the first *four* digits of "code 1" match with first *four* digits of "code 2" (also consider ',' - the four digits should be matched with any one of "code 2")

I have to change the Fruit group for rows 3 and 4 since no match is found:

- If digits do not match then check `temp_code`:
  if `temp_code == True` --> Banana else Orange

Can anyone help me with this?

**Data:**

```
x = [("12E5-11", "12E5-11", "Apple", True), ("12E5-11", "ERE5-11,12E5-11", "Apple", True), ("12E5-11", "MMMM-11", "Apple", True ), ("12E5-11", "XXXX-11" ,"Apple", False), ("12E5-11", "12E5-11", "Apple", True), ("12E5-11", "ERE5-11,12E5-11", "Apple", True)]

Fruits_df = spark.createDataFrame(x, schema=["code 1", "code 2","Fruit_Group","temp_code"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rlike` to check if `code 2` contains a code starting with the first 4 characters of `code 1`. If those characters are 1234, the first subtlety is to avoid matching with something that contains 1234 but does not start with 1234. For that, we can add `(^|,)` at the beginning of the regex. The second subtlety is that `rlike` in spark (python and scala) can only be used with a fixed string and not with a column, except when used inside `expr` :-) Once you have checked whether or not `code 2` matches your criteria, you can use `when` to change your fruit accordingly:

```py
Fruits_df\
    .withColumn("pattern", F.concat(F.lit("(^|,)"), F.substring("code 1", 0, 4)))\
    .withColumn("Fruit_Group", 
        F.when(F.expr("`code 2` rlike `pattern`"), F.col("Fruit_Group"))
         .when(F.col("temp_code"), F.lit("Banana"))
         .otherwise(F.lit("Orange"))
    ).show()
```

```
+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| code 1|         code 2|Fruit_Group|temp_code|  pattern|
+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+
|12E5-11|        12E5-11|      Apple|     true|(^|,)12E5|
|12E5-11|ERE5-11,12E5-11|      Apple|     true|(^|,)12E5|
|12E5-11|        MMMM-11|     Banana|     true|(^|,)12E5|
|12E5-11|        XXXX-11|     Orange|    false|(^|,)12E5|
|12E5-11|        12E5-11|      Apple|     true|(^|,)12E5|
|12E5-11|ERE5-11,12E5-11|      Apple|     true|(^|,)12E5|
+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Can you explain what regex `(^|,)` is doing? is it dividing the string ` ERE5-11,12E5-11` to two codes and check `ERE5` and `12E5`?

Comment: Can you also paste how `pattern` column looks?

Comment: `^` means beginning of the string. `|` means or. So `(^|,)` means either the beginning of the string or a comma. Therefore we are looking for any occurrence of the 4 first chars of code 1 at the beginning of the code 2 or after a comma (that is at the beginning of any code contained in code 2).

Comment: Fruits_df\ what does this do ? Can I write `Fruits_df = Fruits_df.withColumn()` instead?

Comment: the \ is simply there to be able to go to the line in python. Notice that there is one as well at the end of the second line.

Comment: The code is not able to campare the strings using rlike - My code 2 looks like `EE51-11-22-33, ES43-22-33-44, MMMM- 11-22-33 , ERES-11-33-22` - this is not getting compared using `(^|,)`

Comment: I tried by creatiung a new column to check what are returning true ``Fruits_df= Fruits_df.withColumn("check",  F.when(F.expr(("`code 2` rlike `pattern`"), 'True'))`` -- It returns true only if the 4 digits are at the start - It is not able to identify the `,`

Comment: If you have spaces, use `(^|,) *` instead of `(^|)`